# Data in the table is created automatically when the linked table is imported

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 linked tables, how do I enter data in the column key except for table 1, but in the link column 2 tables will AUTOMATICALLY appear that data?
Example: I have table 1 with a column named WW (which is the primary key) and table 2 has a column named WW (which is a foreign key). These 2 tables are linked together. How can I do when I enter data in the WW column of table 2, this data automatically appears in the WW column of table 1.
Or vice versa

Comment: You possibly want ON UPDATE CASCADE see - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15. If not please clarify by adding simplified table definitions, sample data update statement an expected outcome as text to the question.

Comment: Your last edit is a substantial change. Please clarify what and how you are importing.

Comment: Example: I have table 1 with a column named WW (which is the primary key) and table 2 has a column named WW (which is a foreign key). These 2 tables are linked together. How can I do when I enter data in the WW column of table 2, this data automatically appears in the WW column of table 1.

Comment: I can enter it manually via SQL Server "Edit Top 200 rows" or any command that might help me.

Comment: 'How can I do when I enter data in the WW column of table 2, this data automatically appears in the WW column of table 1' - you can't and even if you could it would defeat the object of having a foreign key. as for vice-versa see my first comment.

Comment: 'I can enter it manually via SQL Server "Edit Top 200 rows" - no you can't you can edit rows using SSMS or some other ide - what ide are you using and by edit to you mean add/insert or edit as in update or edit as in delete?

Comment: So is there a way for me to enter data in column ww (primary key) that column ww (foreign key) automatically displays the data of ww (primary key) I just entered?

Answer (score 1):

at first, You can enter in the foreign key column that data which is in other table's primary key.
If you want other data, you should add in other table's primary column